# Some properties are not sent (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, reactjs

So I have an ecommerce site and when I'm trying to create the order and send all the details, only id and quantity are sent? How can I solve this?

This is my code: Success.jsx

```
const Success = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  //in Cart.jsx I sent data and cart. Please check that page for the changes.(in video it's only data)
  const data = location.state.stripeData;
  const cart = location.state.products;
  console.log(data);
  console.log(location.state.products);
  const currentUser = useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser);
  const [orderId, setOrderId] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const createOrder = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await userRequest.post('/orders', {
          username: currentUser.username,
          products: cart.products.map((item) => ({
            productId: item._id,
            quantity: item._quantity,
            title: item._title,
            size: item._size,
            color: item._color,
          })),
          amount: cart.total,
          address: data.billing_details.address,
          status: data.status,
        });
        setOrderId(res.data._id);
      } catch {}
    };
    data && createOrder();
  }, [cart, data, currentUser.username]);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        height: '100vh',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }}
    >
      {orderId
        ? `Order has been created successfully. Your order number is ${orderId}`
        : `Successfull. Your order is being prepared...`}
      <Link to="/">
        <button style={{ padding: 10, marginTop: 20 }}>Go to Homepage</button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And then when I try to display the order I can only see `productId` and `quantity`

Orders.jsx:

```
const Orders = () => {
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const getOrders = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await userRequest.get('orders');
        setOrders(res.data);
      } catch (error) {}
    };
    getOrders();
  }, []);
  console.log(orders.username);
  return (
    <Info>
      {orders.map((order) => (
        <Product>
          <ProductDetail>
            <Details>
              <CustomerName>
                <b>Customer:</b> {order.username}
              </CustomerName>
              <ProductId>
                <b>ID:</b> {order._id}
              </ProductId>
              {order.products.map((product) => (
                <OrderProducts>
                  <b>Products:</b> {product.title}
                </OrderProducts>
              ))}
            </Details>
          </ProductDetail>
          <PriceDetail>
            <ProductAmountContainer>
              <Add />
              <ProductAmount>{order.quantity}</ProductAmount>
              <Remove />
            </ProductAmountContainer>
            <ProductPrice> $ {order.price * order.quantity}</ProductPrice>
          </PriceDetail>
        </Product>
      ))}

      <Hr />
    </Info>
  );
};
```

So here when I try to display `product.title`, it doesn't show up on the frontend.

const res = await userRequest.get('orders');:

```
products
: 
Array(2)
0
: 
productId
: 
"630629baa6774bf0a6849399"
quantity
: 
1
_id
: 
"638771904b9a1d7dc88c2281"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

Order.js(backend):

```
const OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    products: [
      {
        productId: {
          type: String,
        },
        quantity: {
          type: Number,
          default: 1,
        },
        title: {
          type: String,
        },
        size: {
          type: Array,
        },
        color: {
          type: Array,
        },
      },
    ],

    amount: { type: Number, required: true },
    address: { type: Object, required: true },
    status: { type: String, default: 'pending' },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', OrderSchema);
```

order.js(backend)

```
//CREATE

router.post('/', verifyTokenAndAuthorization, async (req, res) => {
  const newOrder = new Order(req.body);

  try {
    const savedOrder = await newOrder.save();
    res.status(200).json(savedOrder);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Others are propably `undefined`

Comment: And what should I do? I can't figure it out.

Comment: `console.log(cart)` and see if the values are there

Comment: I checked and all of the values are there

Comment: What's wrong then?

Comment: Could you also post he response of this request ? (const res = await userRequest.get('orders');)

Comment: I just posted it. Apperantly this does not return all the values

Comment: So maybe there are some bugs in your backend. Are you sure the fields are sent and stored properly ?

Comment: I just checked and I didn't have the title, color, and size properties in the mongoose schema, and I added them, now they are sending except the title. Do you know why that is? I attached the code above

Comment: Could you also add the code which saves the data and also the code which returns the data ?

Comment: Yes, I will send them in a few minutes

Comment: I just added the code.

Comment: And now just the ```title``` value is missing